# how to increase space between radio buttons in radio group in android

Tags: android

I have a header row which is actually some fields header put in horizontal linear layout. Below that row i have five other rows which are either radio buttons or edit boxes which represents values which user will select for each column. Let's say i have three elements in header e.i A, B, C. A has four values i.e PQR,STU,VWX,YZA and B has 3 values i.e CVB,SDF,WER and C is a radio button for boolean value true or false as shown below.

s.n     A         B       C
      PQR STU VWX YZA   CVB SDF WER     X
 1     O   O   O   O     O   O   O     []
 2     O   O   O   O     O   O   O     []

The problem is radio buttons are not inline with the column of first row. And i am getting something like this.

s.n     A         B       C
      PQR STU VWX YZA   CVB SDF WER     X
 1    O O O O  O O O     []
 2    O O O O  O O O     []

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to RadioButtons:

XML solution :

1. Instead of using android:drawableRight on radio buttons, use android:drawableLeft.

or

2. If you want them to share screen width equally you need to set android:layout_width="match_parent" on each View. For details on the implementation you can refer [how to increase space between radio buttons in radio group in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770705/how-to-increase-space-between-radio-buttons-in-radio-group-in-android)

Programmatically Achieving this :

To solve this programmatically you can try adding padding and margins to radio buttons example myButton.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);

More information on details are in this example [android add padding between radiogroup buttons programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951848/android-add-padding-between-radiogroup-buttons-programmatically)

Hope that this helps.

Comment: Sorry the example i posted didn't come in the format i wanted. I am doing it programmatically so can't use xml.

Comment: I have added programmatic way of solving this.